# Is it safe to rely on zip to find data corruption in transmitted zip files?

Tags: ftp, file-transfer, zip, tcp, error-correction

In one paper I read that we can detect errors in the transmitted file by zipping and unzip, but I have doubts.

> For data integrity check, what if we do some operations before
>   sending the data
>
> ```
> If you cannot unzip at the receiving end, then you know that some bits must have
> switched (presumably, CRC not catching it)
> ```

I wondered, could we be sure all data errors were detected by doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know at least one widely-deployed .zip implementation that does not check checksums when decompressing, so I don't recommend relying on .zip checksum checking unless you dictate which .zip decompression implementations everyone involved is allowed to use.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, could you tell me the name?

Comment: Unfortunately, it's macOS's built-in decompression/unarchiving code that is automatically invoked when you double-click on a .zip file (or other archive file) in the macOS Finder (filesystem browser). That code is probably also used in iOS and iPadOS, so decompressing zip files in the Files app in iOS and iPadOS probably doesn't check checksums either.